# facebook login no dialog prompt

Tags: facebook, react-native

I have integrated react-native-fbsdk (v1.1.0) to react-native app and able to login with facebook successfully (i do get the access token, public profile info like name etc).

```
LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile']).then(...);
```

However, it does not have a dialog prompt. Not sure about in iOS though.
I am expecting dialog prompt of something like this but it just login right after i click the login button without any need of confirmation from user.
The flow looks kinda weird to me.

Am i missing some configuration?

Comment: Same issue for me, have you tried on real device or emulator?

Comment: @Ajith yes i tried on real device. I am not sure whether this is default behaviour. But this do seems weird to me.

Comment: what i believe is the first time it asked for permission in a dialogue box right? and after that it logins automatically right?

Comment: @GauravRoy nope i don't think so. But in case that is what it is, how could i revoke the permission so that i could try to restest login with the prompt? And is there any configuration that i can use to force dialog to prompt for subsequent login should that be the case?

Comment: Yes, of course that is how it works - users do not get bothered with the login dialog again, if they have granted everything that is asked for already. If you need to remove permissions, you can do it f.e. via Graph API Explorer, or under https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications